# Which level should I play to get the Nom Nom Nom achievement?

Tags: achievements, plants-vs-zombies

The Nom Nom Nom achievement requires stopping the zombies using only the Sunflower, Wallnut, and Chomper.

I've tried playing the first level a few times with just those plants, but the zombies get through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first couple levels should be work. There is a couple things you want to focus on

- Focus on sunflowers early on the level, plant them horizontally instead of vertically at first. It is ok for the first one or two zombies to get to the lawnmowers, focus on sunflowers first.
- Plant sunflowers where the zombies got the lawn mowers and start building up chompers
- Don't be afraid to use sunflowers as barriers on the first vertical row if you don't have wall nuts available
- If a chomper is currently eating a zombie and is being attacked himself, remove the current chomper and plant a new one

Comment: and don't forget to buy a rake, every little bit helps

Comment: I found that if a chomper is eating a zombie and being attacked, that I can plant a new chomper behind the first.  The new chomper will grab the attacking zombie in the next square.